# How to change a stored actions noun or the overall current action in Inform7?

Tags: action, inform7

EDIT: Massive cleanup, to make the current status clearer!

I want to modify an action in either of two aspects:
Either change the noun in an action previously retrieved by `current action` **not** in the same turn
*or*
Change the action name of the current (or stored) action (so change waiting to unlocking it with).

I tried:

- directly accessing the noun of a stored action: `now the noun of storedAction is`
- accessing the action name of the current action as well as the one stored by the poor attempt of `now the action name part of current action is`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a really hacky feeling solution to my problem. I switched an extra truthstate, repeated the stored action (using try) and then modified noun and second noun according to my needs.
I am not happy with what I had to come up with to get this to work, but this seemed to be the only way possible.

If there will be posted any other solutions to this that are cleaner I will mark them as correct.